# How to check if the pipeline exists in the Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to dynamically run  a data factory pipeline based on the the master pipeline parameter value. The parameter value is in the pipeline name.
For example, My main pipeline name is : MasterLoadData and my child pipelines are:
LoadDataCAN, LoadDataEUR, LoadDataNYK etc The location names CAN, EUR, NYK etc are the parameters.

Each of these pipelines performs unique functionality. I have multiple pipelines (approx 30) in this way. Instead of hardcoding the pipelines in the switch activity, I would like to use the web activity and dynamically construct the pipeline name and then run it.

I want to be able to verify if the child pipeline exists before I trigger the web activity. Is there a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the list of pipeline names in your data factory by calling this [HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/list-by-factory#pipelineresource).

1. Get the list of pipelines using web activity.

**URL**: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines?api-version=2018-06-01`

**Method**: `GET`

2. Pass the output of web activity to a ForEach activity to loop each pipeline.
3. Inside ForEach activity, you can validate the current item (pipeline name: `item().name`) and perform the required activities.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwbaltRKFTU) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzDataFactoryPipeline -ResourceGroupName $v1ResourceGroupName -Name $fileNameOnly -DataFactoryName $v1DataFactoryName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;